# To append into jtextarea from another jtextarea using jbutton

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, jtextarea

I have developed a swing GUI in which I try to populate a text area with the text from another text area using button.

Code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     

jTextArea2.setText(4.0+" "+jTextArea1.getText().trim());
jTextArea1.setText("")
}
```

It is working fine if I enter the text first time in TextArea1 and hit the button to populate the TextArea2. But if I enter a new text in TextArea1 and hit the button instead of appending it to the TextArea2 it replaces the text.

Please suggest me how to correct the same.

Comment: how about using the method `void append(String)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke `append` no `setText`

```
jTextArea2.append(4.0+" "+jTextArea1.getText().trim());
```